# Missing partial outside of views directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, templates, partials

I have a rails 4 app where I have some .ejs templates that look like:

> **app/assets/javascripts/templates/products/template1.jst.ejs**

basically I'm just trying to use Rails to render them as erb:

```
 <%= render :file => "#{Rails.root}/assets/javascripts/templates/products/template1.jst.ejs", :formats => [:erb], w:w, widgetLength: i %>
```

But I get the error: `ActionView::MissingTemplate`

Comment: just to be clear. In what use case will you need to render a file from assets?

Comment: @henrymason, In the .ejs code, I have some html that I use twice, once when I call it using javascript, and later need the same code. I used to have two seperate files, one that is erb and one that is ejs, but it's hard to maintain two copies of basically duplicate html.

Comment: I think that when you give :format, it try to append to the template. This might be giving you your error or missing template.